# I cannot connect by jupyter notebook to my database

Tags: mysql, database, jupyter-notebook

Here is the code I initiate inside my notebook using VS Code. The output is always, NameError: name 'sql' is not defined.
Note: I already do the, pip install mysql and pip install mysql-connector-python

```
 db_connect = sql.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', database = 'ml_database', user = 'root', password = '1234')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the mysql.connector package. I think you might find [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-python-with-sql-database/) helpful.

Comment: yes sir I've already done that, but still it doesn't work

Comment: With the data you provided, it is hard to totally understand your issue. But the name error comes from that you did not install any package name called `sql`. You could replace your import line with `import mysql.connector as sql`.

Comment: Thank I have resolved my problem now. I just have to uninstall and install the packages